# Hadoop FileSystem clear and copy file

Tags: hadoop, copy, filesystems

I am trying to clear the content of fileA, and then copy the content from one fileB to fileA, how can I do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete and copy

```
hadoop fs -rm URI_A
hadoop fs -cp URI_B URI_A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and how can I do it in the code? using FileUtil.copy() or something else? (both files are in hadoop filesystem)

Comment: Unfortunately FileUtils don't provide any function for that. You can either read and write, copy to local and back to remote or use DistCp.

Answer (score 0):

[`FileSystem.create()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29), [`FileSystem.delete()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#delete%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean%29), [`FileSystem.rename()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#rename%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29). You obtain the `FileSystem` usually via the static [`.get(Conf)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#get%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29). FileSystem is abstract and can operate on HDFS or other filesystems (eg. [`wasb://`](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/)).